# Flutter: non-static method registerWith(Registrar) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-plugin

Im working on a flutter plugin that handles the generation of a service.
However recently i found an issue with the **GeneratedPluginRegistrant** that Flutter-Framework uses.

When i execute this command:

> flutter run

The result is a Build Failured with the following message.

> GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:14: error: non-static method
> registerWith(Registrar) cannot be referenced from a static context
> FloatyHeadPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("ni.devotion.floaty_head.FloatyHeadPlugin"));

However as far i know on the Plugin Kotlin Class that function isn't related inside a Companion to be handled as a static function, and it doesn't matter if i change that the error won't go away...

```
class FloatyHeadPlugin : Activity(), MethodCallHandler {
    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: FloatyHeadPlugin
        var activity: Activity? = null
        var context: Context? = null
        var sBackgroundFlutterView: FlutterNativeView? = null
        var sIsIsolateRunning = AtomicBoolean(false)
        private var channel: MethodChannel? = null
        private var backgroundChannel: MethodChannel? = null
    }
    fun registerWith(pluginRegistrar: Registrar) {
        context = pluginRegistrar.context()
        channel = MethodChannel(pluginRegistrar.messenger(), METHOD_CHANNEL)
        channel?.setMethodCallHandler(FloatyHeadPlugin())
    }
```

if you wanna see more detail about it,you can also check the github repo is in the branch

> feature/code_enhancement

[GITHUB REPOSITORY](https://github.com/Crdzbird/floaty_chathead/tree/feature/code_enhancement)

Someone knows how to solve this issue? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... for anyone having this problem, the solution is to implement in your FlutterPlugin Class, the extension ActivityAware.

And implement the following functions:

```
override fun onDetachedFromEngine(binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        channel?.setMethodCallHandler(null)
        //release()
    }

  override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
      channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, METHOD_CHANNEL)
      channel?.setMethodCallHandler(this)
  }

  override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
      activity = binding.activity
      instance = this@FloatyHeadPlugin
  }

  override fun onDetachedFromActivity() {
      //release()
  }

  override fun onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
      activity = binding.activity
  }

  override fun onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges() {
      //release()
  }
```